# Sending hundreds of thousand of personalized emails via API

Tags: email, api

Our organization wants to use SalesForce as gateway for sending bulky amount of personalized emails over API.

Amount is 50K-500K emails per each sending. So far we use SendGrid transactional emails for this purpose. We want to allow sending through SalesForce too.

Is this possible?

We would either:

- send every email individually with 20 threads concurrently
- send emails in batches of N emails per batch and lower concurrency

Also I would be very glad to know a proper way to find delivery status for each of the emails.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce specifically prevent you from sending bulk email directly through their email facilities.

> You can send mass email to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses
>   per day per org based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

So, your best bet would be to write an integration from SF to SendGrid and get SendGrid to send the emails. I've done this for a number of customers and it can work really well. SendGrid can send notifications back to SF regarding open, read, bounce events.